# iOS: How to make factory method work with subclassing

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, initialization, subclassing

I have a class of type `Matrix` which I'd like to subclass. Let's call my subclass `Column`. I'd like to add new properties to my subclass as well. I love factory methods, and don't like to repeat code, so I create a factory method in my subclass which calls its superclass' factory method when initializing an object.

The problem is that if I create an instance of my `Column` class, and call a property only found in `Column`, I get an error, because my `Column` class' factory method which calls my `Matrix` class' factory method is returning an instance of type `Matrix` instead of `Column` or whatever subclass calls it. I understand why this happens, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

I've read the following [article](http://qualitycoding.org/factory-method/) on factory methods, and know that instead of using `[[Matrix alloc] init];` I should be using `[[self alloc] init];`. The problem is I'm not sure how I'd access my instance variables like `matrix`, `rows` and `freeData` which I define in my header as follows:

```
@interface Matrix : NSObject <NSCoding, NSCopying> {

    @public     double  *matrix;
    @public     int     rows;
    @public     int     columns;
    @private    BOOL    freeUpData;
}
```

Here's the factory method I need help in. How can I rewrite it so it can access my instance variables, and also work with subclassing (and not only return a `Matrix` instance).

```
+ (instancetype)matrixFromArray:(double *)arr Rows:(int)m Columns:(int)n Mode:(refMode)mode
{
    Matrix *mt = [[Matrix alloc] init];
    if (mode == YCMCopy) {

        double *new_m = malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));
        memcpy(new_m, arr, m*n*sizeof(double));
        mt->matrix = new_m;
        mt->freeData = YES;
    }

    else {
        mt->matrix = arr;
        mt->freeData = NO;
    }

    if (mode != YCMWeak) {
        mt->freeData = YES;
    }

    mt->rows = m;
    mt->columns = n;

    return mt;
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking?  A subclass can't return a superclass instance, it can only return a subclass, but this won't matter due to the Liskov Substitution Principle - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: @Paulw11 Just updated my answer, hopefully that clarifies my question. Would appreciate it if you changed your vote to close. Also you're incorrect. My subclass is returning a superclass instance because of how my superclass factory method is written. I'd like to know how to update it to make subclassing possible.

Comment: You can't this superclass factory method from a subclass because you will always get the superclass - as you have found.  You can change your factory method to separate the allocation from the initialisation - then you can allocate the object in the subclass and then call `[super doInitialisation]`

Comment: Ahh I see any chance you can show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always create Matrix instance 
but you need to create instance of current class

```
+ (instancetype)matrix
{
    Matrix *mt = [[self alloc] init];
....
    return mt;
}
```

And if you do that

[Matrix matrix] will return Matrix object

[Column matrix] will return Column object

Comment: Damn I love you @oxigen. For some reason I was overthinking it and felt like `Matrix *mt` needed to be something like `self mt`, etc.